# Help for custom menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7

Drupal 7 `hook_menu()` is confusing me; I have tried everything and I can't seem to get this to work.

**What I need:** In a custom module, I'd like to create a new menu, and add about four links to that menu. It sounds simple, but I am struggling. I've been able to create the menu itself using the $menu array in the .install file, but adding items to that menu doesn't make sense.

**Code that is working:**

```
$menu = array(
  'menu_name' => 'project-menu', 
  'title' => $t('Project Menu'), 
  'description' => 'Project Menu',
); 

menu_save($menu);
```

**Code that isn't working:**

```
$items = array();

$items['project-menu/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'Test Link',
  'page callback' => 'dc_project_page',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);

return $items;
```

This is all in the dc_project.install file under the `dc_project_menu()` function. Hopefully I'm just doing something stupid, any and all help is extremely appreciated. Even just pointing to me to a module that does this cleanly as an example, thanks. I did look at the example project, haven't been able to get anything as far as adding links to my new menu working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing to [menu_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--menu--menu.module/function/menu_save/7) the content of `$items` doesn't work because `menu_save()` accepts only an array containing `menu_name`, `title`, and `description`.
What you use in `$items` is an array describing the menu callbacks implemented by a module, and the definitions of the menu callbacks implemented by all the modules are not saved in "menu_custom" (the table used from `menu_save()`) but are cached in a Drupal cache table.

If you are trying to change the menu callbacks defined by another module, then you should implement [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7); otherwise, if you just want do define the menu callbacks of your module, you should implement [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

Both the hooks implementations (`hook_menu()` and `hook_menu_alter()`) must be in the module file (in your case, in dc_project.module), not in dc_project.install. Drupal doesn't load the installation file when it normally loads the enabled modules; it loads the installation file when a module is being updated (or installed), but it doesn't load it in other cases.
The code that saves the menu with `menu_save()` can be in the installation file, in the implementation of [hook_install()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) or [hook_update_N()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7). It could also be put in the implementation of [hook_enable()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7); in that case, the code (which is executed when the module is enabled) should first verify the menu has not been already added. (`hook_enable()` and `hook_disable()` should be placed in the installation file.)

Comment: wow, I haven't attempted to fix my code using your guidance. But that was extremely informative, thank so much. Feel like I have a much better understanding of the drupal menu system.